# Tesseract + opencv 3.0 + windows, text module small size, linking errors

Tags: windows, opencv, visual-studio-2012, tesseract

I posted this text two days ago in answers.opencv.org, now I'm posting it here as well. http://answers.opencv.org/question/68634/text-contrib-module-and-tesseract/

> Good afternoon to everyone. First of all, sorry for my english hehe.
>   I've been trying to build the opencv contrib module 'text', however I
>   haven't got sucess. Note: Other modules like xfeatures2d have never
>   given me a problem.
>
> My platform is windows 7 x64 and I use VS2013 as compiler, I've
>   followed this
>   tutorial(http://vorba.ch/2014/tesseract-3.03-vs2013.html) in order to
>   build Tesseract 3.04 as LIB, but after compiling it succesfully, I
>   want to generate the vproj with cmake and the problem is the
>   following:
>
> In CMake GUI, having previously selected opencv source, EXTRAS
>   directory, etc etc, I don't get the vars under 'Tesseract' group set
>   correcly (INCLUDE AND LIBS). I know it because when I click on
>   configure, The log says "Tesseract: NO".
>
> I've inspected the FindTesseract cmake script and I think that it
>   doesn't work....
>
> Please, anyone could give me a little clue about what's happening? How
>   can I build the opencv text module to use Tesseract functions?
>
> Also I've tried to compile text module adding link paths to Tesseract
>   but when I want to use in my program I get link errors about undefined
>   symbols...
>
> This situation is taking me serveral days bothering me. Are there
>   someone who is using text module under windows?

---

Nobody can help me? I've made some progress, now cmake GUI, says me Tesseract:Yes. The problem was that I hadn't found the entry for linking the leptonica lib, which's not in the same Tesseract group but in 'Ungrouped Entries'.

Ok, now the problem remains same, the VS solution created by cmake is not building the text module correctly as I can see Lept lib is about 9Mb and TesseractLib is 128Mb (in /MT and debug), however the opencv_text300d.lib is only 12Mb. Something is wrong....

I'm not sure about what tesseract version I must use. I've traid with two combinations:
liblept168-static-mtdll-debug.lib + libtesseract302-static-debug.lib
and
liblept171-static-mtdll-debug.lib + libtesseract304-static-debug.lib

Of course when I link text module to my program it gives me link errors.

---

The linking errors look like: opencv_text300d.lib(ocr_tesseract.obj) : error `LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __cdecl tesseract::PageIterator::BoundingBox(enum tesseract::PageIteratorLevel,int *,int *,int *,int *)const " (?........................`

---

```
...
#include "opencv2/text.hpp"
...
string output;
cv::Mat aux;
Ptr<OCRTesseract> ocr = OCRTesseract::create();
ocr->run(aux, output);
...
```

Obviously I've set up my project with additional include directories, linker additional library directory and input additional dependecies to the text module.

Really, thank you so very much in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same problem. The solution I came up with was to edit the CMakeLists.txt file in text module.

Replace

```
if(${Tesseract_FOUND})
include_directories(${Tesseract_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()
```

with

```
add_definitions( -DWINDOWS)
add_definitions( -DNOMINMAX)
SET(Tesseract_DIR "C:\\tesseract-build\\tesseract-ocr")
SET(Lept_DIR "C:\\tesseract-build\\lib")
include_directories(
        ${Tesseract_DIR}/api
        ${Tesseract_DIR}/ccutil/
        ${Tesseract_DIR}/ccstruct/
        ${Tesseract_DIR}/ccmain/
    )
link_directories( ${Tesseract_DIR}/vs2013/bin/Win32/DLL_Release/
                  ${Lept_DIR}/
                  ${Lept_DIR}/Win32/
                )
```

When you run Cmake, Tesseract will still be no and the Tessaract/Lept libraries should be empty.

Comment: Thank you so very much! It's make sense!

Comment: I didn't understand the change made in the file, including leptonica library before generating opencv text module with tesseract? I have similar problem but with tesseract 3.05 and opencv3.2 generated from source code with cmake.