# OpenCV 3.0 + Text Module - Tesseract not found during runtime

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, visual-studio-2013, tesseract

I am trying to get the currently external Text module, which uses Tesseract, running in OpenCV. I tried every possible combination and found a few useful hints, but I am out of ideas now. I am using Windows 10 64-bit and Visual Studio 2013.

I got everything compiled and I can code a basic example but when run the program I get the following output in the program window: Tesseract not found
[Picture: Tesseract error during runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wb3R.png)

I set up the program with all includes and libs and the Tesseract not found message is printed at the following two lines:

```
Ptr<OCRTesseract> ocr = OCRTesseract::create();
ocr->run(image, output);
```

I am compiling Tesseract for VS2013 and then compiling OpenCV with CMake. I also found this Stackoverflow question: [Tesseract + opencv 3.0 + windows, text module small size, linking errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038445/tesseract-opencv-3-0-windows-text-module-small-size-linking-errors)

I could reproduce that linker error and also fix it with the given answer, but when I run the program I get the "Tesseract not found" message. I also added Tesseract and Leptonica manually in CMake and compiled successfully with Tesseract but I got the same message when running my program.
I compiled OpenCV both in Debug and Release 64 mode and set my test program accordingly.

Why is Tesseract not found by OpenCV when it could compile correctly?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Did you figure out?>