# Linking OpenCV to tesseract for contrib module - windows cmake

Tags: python, windows, opencv, cmake, tesseract

I am trying to build opencv with contrib modules (done) and link the text module with tesseract.

I downloaded the tesseract pre-built binary for windows, and confirmed its in my path

```
Ben@Ben-Laptop MINGW64 ~
$ tesseract -v
tesseract 3.05.00dev
 leptonica-1.73
  libgif 4.1.6(?) : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.4.2) : libpng 1.6.20 : libtiff 4.0.6 : zlib 1.2.8 : libwebp 0.4.3 : libopenjp2 2.1.0
```

When I go to build in cmake, i see the following config option.

[image]

But it does not link on build ("tesseract:no"). I think its likely because OpenCV is looking for the tesseract library built from source, but this has been a complete minefield (cppan errors, cmake errors). Is there anyway to point opencv to the binary?

I found some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038445/tesseract-opencv-3-0-windows-text-module-small-size-linking-errors), but without being able to build tesseract from source, i don't I can do anything to the cmake file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To allow CMake to detect and set Tesseract:YES, apart from tesseract lib, you need to config lept_library pointing to leptonica lib as well. Ensure tesseract include path has tesseract\baseapi.h. Use git to clone the source if you don't have it.